# Wordpress error with my basic PHP form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WP_MAIL to submit a contact form from my wordpress website. 
I have two files, one for the HTML form and one for the PHP function. When i hit submit however the function doesn't seem to fire. I have tested wp_mail and it is working. The strange thing is, this function was workign on Monday and now it is not.

Here is a basic version of my HTML and the full PHP function.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name ="name" placeholder="your name">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name ="email" placeholder="your email">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name ="number" placeholder="your number">

</form>
<?php
add_action('wp', 'send_my_awesome_form');

function send_my_awesome_form(){

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { return; }

// get the info from the from the form
$form = array();
$form['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$form['number'] = $_POST['number'];
$form['email'] = $_POST['email'];

// Build the message
$message  = "Name :" . $form['name'] ."\n";
$message .= "Number :" . $form['number'] ."\n";
$message .= "Email :" . $form['email'] ."\n";


//set the form headers
$headers = 'From: The Website';

// The email subject
$subject = 'Booking Request';

// Who are we going to send this form too
$send_to = 'myemailaddress@mydomain.com';

if (wp_mail( $send_to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
     wp_redirect('http://www.urltogoto.com'); exit;
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: review everything you changed since monday.  are you using any kind of version control?

Comment: I did, it took me seconds to review it and then remembered that I didnt work on Tuesday lol. None the less, Im now getting a white screen when I click submit an my console shows a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming (for example temporarily prefixing) your form field names. The name "name" (amongst others) is reserved in WordPress causing a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You must take one by one php line to check, if you don`t see any error`s.
you can try this first
comment this line `//if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { return; }`.
if you will be  redirected to http://www.urltogoto.com then you have an problem with your if statement.